# wpf change combobox background from application resources

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I want to Change the Background and the Dropdown Background of all comboboxes to an Image, the hoover color to transparent and the hoover-border color to white. I tried to bind styles on "combobox", "comboboxItem" and "checkbox" but it doesnt work.
This is my Code for my Combobox:

```
 <ComboBox Margin="0,0,0,2" DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTagsForFilter}" Height="23" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="SEGOWP" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding TagFilterText}" IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" Focusable="False">
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Content="{Binding Name}" Height="25">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdChx_UpdateSearchTags, ElementName=self}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Unchecked">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.CmdChx_UpdateSearchTags, ElementName=self}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

and the style layout I currently use is like this:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.WindowStyleProp, ElementName=self, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static enum:WindowStylesEnum.Dark}">
                <Setter Property="Background" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ImageBrush TileMode="FlipY" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentY="Top" Viewport="0,0,33,34" ViewportUnits="Absolute" ImageSource="{StaticResource DarkBackground2}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.WindowStyleProp, ElementName=self, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Static enum:WindowStylesEnum.Default}">
                <Setter Property="Background" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" >
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I want to have something like this so I can Change the properties if the enum is changed.

Comment: The question says he dont want to Change the Dropdown Background.

Comment: But there are the answers,which answers your questions.